# Unable to validate LUKS encryption

Tags: linux, centos, encryption, luks

Hello I have a question about LUKS encryption. I have used LUKS to encrypt a disk on my server but when I create a file and add content to it, and cat the file, the content is still in plain text. Even when I create a backup of the file, and put it on the non-encrypted hard drive, the data is in plain text. I'm not sure how I can say that encryption is happening. Am I missing something? Is this how LUKS is supposed to work?

```
/dev/sdb: UUID="d7f667ed-50a4-4324-8708-6720d390bfd2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
[root@host1 ~]# cat /opt/my_encrypted_backup/test12
This is a test
[root@host1 ~]# clear
[root@host1 ~]# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0    8G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0    7G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0  6.2G  0 lvm   /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  820M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb               8:16   0    1G  0 disk
└─mybackup      253:2    0 1022M  0 crypt /opt/my_encrypted_backup
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
[root@host1 ~]#
[root@host1 ~]#
[root@host1 ~]# blkid /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: UUID="d7f667ed-50a4-4324-8708-6720d390bfd2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
[root@host1 ~]#
[root@host1 ~]#
[root@host1 ~]# cat /opt/my_encrypted_backup/test12
This is a test
[root@host1 ~]# cp /opt/my_encrypted_backup/test12 /
[root@host1 ~]# cat /test12
This is a test
[root@host1 ~]#
```

Comment: LUKS is a "data at rest" encryption scheme. That means the data is only in encrypted form when it is "at rest", such as written to the disk drive. When you are logged in and have entered your decryption passphrase, LUKS works with the kernel to (de/en)crypt the data in between accessing it on the disk (where it is encrypted) and working with it in memory (where it has been decrypted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LUKS/dm-crypt works on the block device level, not on the filesystem level so yes, this is correct and this is how it works.

When you open the encrypted device (`/dev/sdb` in your case) a new virtual device mapper device is created (`/dev/mapper/mybackup` in your case) on top of it. All data on `sdb` is encrypted and `mybackup` is used to access the data in plain -- from system point of view, `mybackup` contains a normal unencrypted filesystem and everything on it is unecrypted, this way the system can work with encrypted data without need for additional encryption support in every application that reads/writes data to disk.

When data is read from `mybackup`, device mapper (kernel module) reads the data from `sdb` and decrypts it before returning it in plain text. Similarly for writes, you write plain text to `mybackup` and before writing to `sdb` it's encrypted. So everything on your disk is accessible in plain text when the device is opened.

So your data is "safe" only when the device is not opened. Main use case for LUKS/dm-crypt (or disk encryption in general) is to protect the data in case of your disk (or entire computer) gets stolen. It does not protect the data when the system is running and the device is opened because the master key is stored in memory, you can get it using `dmsetup table --showkeys`.

Comment: nitpicking: LUKSv2 (without using option `--disable-keyring`)  stores the master key with newer kernel feature that keeps it private to the kernel: the master key can't be recovered back by asking kernel's device mapper subsystem as is possible with LUKSv1.

Comment: @Vojtech Trefny I'm curious, if someone gets the disk without having the passphrase, there is no way (is there?) they can access the data. So what's the point of the encryption? It seems to me it's either you have access or you don't have access. Is there a scenario where someone could have access to cyphertext ?

Comment: @Jean: Yes. However, it is a very unlikely edge case -- Say you are at a bus stop working on your laptop, and someone runs passed you and grabs the laptop. Since you were logged in and the keys are in memory, they can likely access it if you were logged in with any kind of access beyond "plain ordinary user". (An experienced thief would compromise any passwords, encryption, and other security at their earliest opportunity, so they can regain access after a screen lock or shutdown.)